# Custom Debian Live-Build final IMG folder

Tags: iso, debootstrap, live-build

The default output **img** file was at the `lb config` used

Is there any way to custom output img directory ? like output img to directory IMG_1, IMG_2, etc

```
# mkdir /customlive

# cd /customlive

# lb config --binary-image hdd --apt-indices false --apt-recommends false --debootstrap-options "--variant=minbase" --firmware-chroot false --memtest none

# echo "user-setup sudo" > config/package-lists/recommends.list.chroot

# echo "ifupdown isc-dhcp-client" >> config/package-lists/recommends.list.chroot

# lb build 2>&1 | tee build.log
```

Default output:

`/customlive/linux-image-amd64.img`

What I want is :

```
/customlive/lb config
/customlive/IMG_1/lb build
/customlive/IMG_1/linux-image-amd64.img
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
# mkdir -p /customlive/IMG_1
# cd /customlive/IMG_1
        ︙
```